# Yii links not working properly

Tags: yii, yii-components, yii-url-manager

In my Yii application I defined rules in Yii's `urlManager` as follows:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                'izletiste/<grad:\.*?>/<naziv:.*?>/<id:d+>'=>'izletiste/show',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

Now, when I want to create a link, I use the following construction:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($izletiste->nazivIzletista),array("izletiste/show","grad"=>"Paris","naziv"=>"Some text", "id"=>$id)); ?>
```

The url I get is the following:

```
http://mywebsite.com/izletiste/Paris/Some+text/21
```

But when I click on the link, I get the following error:

> #### Error 404
>
> *The system is unable to find the requested action "Paris".*

My question is why is that happening, why Yii doesn't recognize that izletiste/show action should be called instead izletiste/paris, and how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "grad"=>"paris",  it simply doesn't matter if it is Paris or paris!

Comment: I just realized, the regex is wrong at `\.*?` and `d+`. It should be `<grad:\w+>` and `<id:\d+>` respectively. What were you trying to achieve by using `<grad:\.*?>`?

Comment: Yep, that was the second mistake. Thx for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tho change first rule like here:

```
'izletiste/<grad>/<naziv>/<id:\d+>'=>'izletiste/show'
```

Comment: What is the difference between <grad:\.*?> and <grad>?